# Cannot find boost library

Tags: c++, linux, unix, boost

This is a very basic question, I only post because I've spent already some time into it. This is what I've done so far:

1. Downloaded and compiled the boost library:

   `sudo ./bootstrap.sh` and `sudo ./bjam install`

   This way it was installed into `/usr/local/lib`.
2. In my source code I've added only:

   > ```
   > #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   > using boost::asio::ip::tcp
   > ```
3. I compile it with:

   `g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -L/usr/local/lib -fPIC  -lboost_system -shared -o libagent.so agent.cpp`
4. However, `ldd -d ./libagent.so` gives me:

   `libboost_system.so.1.46.1 => not found`
5. But there is no error thrown, when using the `-lboost_system` and `ls /usr/local/lib` gets me among other things:

   `libboost_system.so`
   `libboost_system.a`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you run ldconfig? http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did the `./bjam install` tool also run the `ldconfig(8)` tool? `ldconfig(8)` needs to be run after new libraries are installed to update the caches used by `ld.so(8)` at program execution time.

Comment: this. You need to run (as root) `ldconfig -u`.

Comment: And /usr/local/lib should be in path list of ldconfig.

Comment: Thanks, running sudo ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile it with:

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -fPIC -lboost_system -shared -o libagent.so agent.cpp
```

This makes it look for the boost library in /usr/local/lib at runtime, the -L option only makes it look in /usr/local/lib at compile time.